# Mensagem de erro : Cannot read property 'thisCompilation' of undefined

Tags: typescript, angular, visual-studio-code

Estou utilizando Angular para um projeto e Visual Studio Code quando executo o comando `ng serve`, me devolve o seguinte o erro:

> - NG Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **   0% compiling Cannot read
>     property 'thisCompilation' of undefined

Comment: Qual a versão do **Webpack** ? Tente o seguinte: `npm remove webpack` e `npm install webpack@3.11.0`

Comment: consegui resolve com essa questão https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43304864/angular-2-typeerror-cannot-read-property-profile-of-null-error

Comment: e justamente o que você passou

Comment: "webpack":    "version": "4.0.1",

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esse erro acontece devido um bug na versão **4.0.0**, há varios reportes de bug no *GitHub*

Para corrigir basta remover e instalar versão anterior, como o exemplo a seguir:

```
npm remove webpack
npm install webpack@3.11.0
```

#### Referências

- [Issue 9793](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9793)
- [Issue 9794](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9794)